# AMSART: Change subsection headings from boldface to smallcaps

Tags: sectioning, amsart

In `amsart`, how do you change subsection headings from boldface to smallcaps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `amsart.cls` has

```
\def\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\bfseries}}
```

you just add, in your document preamble (that is, before `\begin{document}`),

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\scshape}}
\makeatother
```

Here's a complete document including the requests made in the comments.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}%
  \z@{-.5\linespacing\@plus-.7\linespacing}{.5\linespacing}%
  {\normalfont\scshape}}
\renewcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}%
  \z@{.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing}{-.5em}%
  {\normalfont\scshape}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Title}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{Title}

\lipsum[3]

\subsubsection{Title}

\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: By the way, how can I leave a line between the subsection heading and the text? And if I wanted to change *sub*subsection headings from italics to smallcaps, what should I do?

Comment: @Ryo Added. I'd leave subsubsections in italics.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How do you add the indentation for the first line of the subsection?

Comment: @Ryo Change `-.5\linespacing\@plus-.7\linespacing` into `.5\linespacing\@plus.7\linespacing`

Comment: How can we centralise the subsection title?